# Lightroom 5: apply to active photo in selection only

Tags: lightroom-5, keyboard-shortcuts

I was flying through my work-flow and my fingers got tangled up... I hit a key combo somehow and the behavior of applying things to the currently active image in a group selected images changed.

Previously, if I had 5 images selected and wanted to reject just the one that I had focus on (the active photo), hitting X would reject just that one.

Now, it's rejected all selected images.

This is really slowing down my workflow so *how do I revert that behavior so that actions such as reject apply to only one photo out of a group of selected photos*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is that Auto-Sync was on. Turn it off and the behavior reverts. (http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?13307-how-do-I-turn-off-auto-sync)

> [Y]ou can use the menu bar: in Library go to Metadata menu and uncheck Enable Auto-Sync. In Develop, the Enable Auto-Sync option is in the Settings menu.

Comment: And how does on turn off Auto-Sync? It would be helpful to include it in the answer.

Comment: The answer to "how" is directly google-able with an "I'm feeling lucky" option so was not really part of the answer and the answer very specifically was that auto-sync was on. However, if you insist: http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?13307-how-do-I-turn-off-auto-sync

Comment: "**Provide context for links**

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

From the answer guidelines at http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The *how* may not have been originally part of your answer, but it was certainly the key part of the question you were attempting to answer! So much so that the writer of the question *italicized* the part that asked how to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, I italicize the actual question so that it stands out from the description - I've been quite long-winded on SO in the past and it helps to do that. While I don't *particularly* agree entirely about providing the "how", I can see where it makes sense and I'll make sure that I do that from now on. Give me a moment and I'll provide the updated info for you. And thanks for the feedback.